# Is there an ISO or public mapping of locations to "olson database" format (e.g. TZInfo / TZ)

Tags: datetime, geolocation, timezone, street-address

There are plenty of resources on olson database flat files and how to work with times in olson database format... but how in the heck is everyone getting their address records to map to a timezone?

For example:

- We have an address "Akron, Ohio, US"
- We want it's timezone in "America/New_York" format

Is there a database that can be queried or referenced? Or is there an ISO file that can be loaded for local reference?

Someone has to have automated this process, I can't imagine we're all manually setting the time zone field to olson TZ's.

Comment: See [this community wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824)